# yii2 display notification more and more in a drop down div when scrolling downward

Tags: php, html, json, yii2, infinite-scroll

I was working in getting notification in select2 kartik widget and every thing was working well, now I am trying to modify my code to get my data in my drop down div, but I don't have an Idea about doing that.

This Is my Code to modify in the view

```
    <div class="dropdown-menu animated flipInX">

    <div class="dropdown-body niceScroll ">

     <!-- Start notification list -->
    <div class="media-list small">
     <a href="#" class="media">
     <?php
     $notificationUrl = Url::to(['site/notification-list']);

    echo Select2::widget([
      'name' => 'state_800',
    'pluginOptions' => [
             'ajax' => [
               'url' => $notificationUrl,
                      'dataType' => 'json',
  'data' => new JsExpression('function(params) { return {q:params.term, page:params.page || 1}; }')
                                                    ],
  'escapeMarkup' => new JsExpression('function (markup) { return markup; }'),
   'templateResult' => new JsExpression('function(product) {;return product.text; }'),
     'templateSelection' => new JsExpression('function (subject) { return subject.text; }'),
                       ],
      ]);
                     ?>
                      </a>
        </div> .......
```

I need to show notifications like this image below 
[image: show them as displayed without using select2 widget]

And this is my action which is working will in retrieving data ;so my problem is just how to display it in my drop down div

```
public function actionNotificationList($page, $q = null, $id = null) {
        $offset = ($page - 1) * 10;

        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        $out = ['results' => ['id' => '', 'text' => '']];
        $query = new Query;
        $query->select(['notification_id as id', new Expression("notification_text AS text")])
                ->from('notification')
                ->offset($offset)
                ->limit(10);

        $command = $query->createCommand();
        $data = $command->queryAll();
        $out['results'] = array_values($data);
        $out['pagination'] = ['more' => !empty($data) ? true : false];
        return $out;
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so what is the problem you are having? is it not displaying you the notifications ?

Comment: no the notifications are inside the select 2; the other notifications are static;so  I want to display them as static noitifications  appears with infinite scroll

Comment: what i am trying to understand is that you are trying to dynamically update the select2 and update the options with any new notification available? or you are trying to only stylize the `select2` as shown in the above picture?

Comment: do select the answer if it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

Well as far as i understood you are trying to dynamically update the options inside the select2 if that is correct you can use the javascript to update the select2 options.

What looks like that your notifications are coming from some database tables and you can send an ajax call to check if there are any unread notifications and return the list of the notifications as JSON and update the `Selec2` options on runtime.

I can demonstrate that with the click of a button as ajax wont be able to implement here on SO, you can replace the button `click` with your ajax call and pass the notifications to the `refreshDataSelect2` function which will update the options.

```js
$('.notifications').select2({
  placeholder: 'Select an option',
  'width': '100%'
});

$.fn.refreshDataSelect2 = function(data) {
  this.select2('data', data);
  // Update options
  var $select = $(this[0]);
  var options = data.map(function(item) {
    return '<option value="' + item.id + '">' + item.text + '</option>';
  });
  $select.append(options.join('')).change();
};

$("#add").on("click", function() {
  let data = [{
    id: $('.notifications').children('option').length + 1,
    text: "A New Message number " + $('.notifications').children('option').length
  }]
  $(".notifications").refreshDataSelect2(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select name="notifications" class="notifications">
  <option>some Message</option>
  <option>Admin Message</option>
  <option>Private Message</option>
</select>
<button id="add">Add Message</button>
```